# Visualize .trk file with VTK

Tags: c++, vtk

I'm trying to find a way to visualize a .trk file with C++ and VTK libraries but I don't understand if I need to convert the file to a format known by VTK or if exists a direct way to display it!
Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: What format is  .trk?

Comment: It's TrackVis format, it's a file that contain information about neural fibers of brain. Here's a link to an [example](https://www.google.it/search?q=trk+file&rlz=1C1AVNC_enIT572IT572&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSuoe06q3JAhUCyRoKHaU_BzgQ_AUICCgC&biw=1366&bih=643#tbm=isch&q=trackvis+file&imgrc=Nm5F4kPEppmX0M%3A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vtk does not have reader for trackvis format. According to this  https://www.nitrc.org/frs/shownotes.php?release_id=724 trackvis v >=0.5 can export vtk format.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know about this feature! :)